# ChangePivotCache Function Works in Excel but not in Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am making a form on Word with a vba macro that takes all the data from the filled out form and outputs it to an Excel file on Teams.  As a part of this code I want it to update the range of the pivot tables in the Excel File.  However when I tried to do this in the word macro, it never worked ( and it wouldn't throw any errors) so I went to Excel to see if I could get the formatting correct there.  I got an Excel macro that updates the range, but when I put it back into the word macro, once I reach the changePivotCache functions nothing happens (no errors and no updating of the pivot tables).  Further,  no code after the changePivotCache will run in my user defined function (its like it just quits the function).

Here is the Excel code that works:

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    
    'Variables
    Dim xlPath As String            'A string of our xl files' pathway
    Dim lastCol As Integer          'The last filled column in our sheet
    Dim lastRow As Integer          'The last filled row in our sheet
    Dim lastCell As String          'The last cell in the sheet with data
    Dim Sheet1 As String            'The first sheet of the wkbk
    Dim xlName As String            'The xl worbooks name
    
    'Code that Finds the last Column and Row
    '...
    
    'Create the last cell String
    lastCell = "R" & lastRow & "C" & lastCol
    MsgBox (lastCell)

    'Format a string representing the range of our data for the pivot tables
    Sheet1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name
    xlPath = "https://TeamsFilePathwayHere/"
    xlName = "testData.xlsm"
    Dim referance As String
    referance = xlPath & "[" & xlName & "]" & Sheet1 & "!R2C1:" & lastCell
    
    'Updating the Pivot
    With Workbooks(xlName)
        .Sheets("WorkerSummary").PivotTables(1).ChangePivotCache _
            Workbooks(xlName).PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            referance, Version:= _
            6)
        .Sheets("Worker Summary").PivotTables(2).ChangePivotCache _
            Workbooks(xlName).PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            referance, Version:= _
            6)
        .Sheets("Location Summary").PivotTables(1).ChangePivotCache _
            Workbooks(xlName).PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            referance, Version:= _
            6)
        .Sheets("Location Summary").PivotTables(2).ChangePivotCache _
            Workbooks(xlName).PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            referance, Version:= _
            6)
        .Sheets("Shift Summary").PivotTables(1).ChangePivotCache _
            Workbooks(xlName).PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            referance, Version:= _
            6)
        .Sheets("Shift Summary").PivotTables(2).ChangePivotCache _
           Workbooks(xlName).PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            referance, Version:= _
            6)
    End With

End Sub
```

And here is the Word code that doesn't work:

```vb
Function updatePivots(xlFileName As Variant, xlName As String, Sheet1 As String, xlApp As Object) As Boolean

    'Variables
    Dim xlPath As String            'A string of our xl files' pathway
    xlPath = Replace(xlFileName, xlName, vbNullString)
    Dim lastCol As Integer          'The last filled column in our sheet
    Dim lastRow As Integer          'The last filled row in our sheet
    Dim lastCell As String          'The last cell in the sheet with data
    Dim reference As String         'The cells we want to update the pivot table to
    
    'Code that finds the last column and row
    '...
    
    'Format a string representing the range of our data for the pivot tables
    lastCell = "R" & lastRow & "C" & lastCol
    referance = xlPath & "[" & xlName & "]" & Sheet1 & "!R2C1:" & lastCell
    'MsgBox (xlApp.Workbooks(xlName).Sheets("Operator Summary").PivotTables(1).Name)

    'Updating the Pivot Tables
    'Any code after this point will not Execute
    xlApp.Workbooks(xlName).Sheets("Worker Summary").PivotTables(1).ChangePivotCache _
        xlApp.Workbooks(xlName).PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        referance, Version:=6)
    'MsgBox (xlApp.Workbooks(xlName).Sheets("Operator Summary").PivotTables(2).Name)
        
    xlApp.Workbooks(xlName).Sheets("Worker Summary").PivotTables(2).ChangePivotCache _
        xlApp.Workbooks(xlName).PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        referance, Version:=6)
        
    xlApp.Workbooks(xlName).Sheets("Location Summary").PivotTables(1).ChangePivotCache _
        xlApp.Workbooks(xlName).PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        referance, Version:=6)
    
    xlApp.Workbooks(xlName).Sheets("Location Summary").PivotTables(2).ChangePivotCache _
        xlApp.Workbooks(xlName).PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        referance, Version:=6)
        
    xlApp.Workbooks(xlName).Sheets("Shift Summary").PivotTables(1).ChangePivotCache _
        xlApp.Workbooks(xlName).PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        referance, Version:=6)
    
    xlApp.Workbooks(xlName).Sheets("Shift Summary").PivotTables(2).ChangePivotCache _
        xlApp.Workbooks(xlName).PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        referance, Version:=6)
        
    'Return true since we are done
    updatePivots = True
    

End Function
```

Comment: Are you using late or early binding when working with Excel (do you have a Word VBA project reference pointing to the Excel object library) ? If using late binding then Excel constants such as `xlDatabase` will have no value.   If you're using `Option Explicit` (which should *always* be there) it will flag these up as undeclared variables.

Comment: ...note for example you have `Dim reference As String` but then later `referance = ...` This would be flagged up on compile if you have `Option Explicit`